# Is it possible to send and receive XML to WSDL function using Delphi..?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl, delphi-2010

We have used Web Services with Delphi in the past and those are simple with few parameters and returned a single value to the client. A new service we working should able to XML input and receive XML output.

Is there any componenet which can be used for this purpose?

When i tried using like below am getting an error "Exception in SearchAgreements input parameter XmlElement - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
  LDocument := NewXMLDocument;
  <<framed an XML input>>
  DocSearchOut := SearchArgsResponse.Create();
  DoxSerchIn := SearchArgs.Create();
  DoxSerchIn.SOAPTOObject(LDocument.DocumentElement,LDocument.DocumentElement,HTTPRIO1.Converter);
  DoxService := GetIDoxService(True,'',HTTPRIO1);
  DocSearchOut :=DoxService.SearchAgreements(DoxSerchIn)
```

I even tried converting SearchArgs as widestring and tried to pass as a string.**This is working with minor changes on HTTPRIO execute. Final Edit**

```
  LDocument := NewXMLDocument;
  <<framed an XML input>>
  DocSearchOut := SearchArgsResponse.Create();
  DoxSerchIn := SearchArgs.Create();
  DoxSerchIn.SearchArgs := LDocument.DocumentElement.XML;
  DoxService := GetIDoxService(True,'',HTTPRIO1);
  DocSearchOut :=DoxService.SearchAgreements(DoxSerchIn)
```

its wsdl

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:i0="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="DoxService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:import namespace="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0" location="http://devldn.ldn.bank.com:8258/doxManual/DoxService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDoxService" type="i0:IDoxService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="SearchAgreements">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0/IDoxService/SearchAgreements" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="DoxService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IDoxService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IDoxService">
<soap:address location="http://devldn.ldn.bank.com:8258/doxManual/DoxService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

wsdl0

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" targetNamespace="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://ldndev.ldn.bank.com:8258/doxManual/DoxService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://ldndev.ldn.bank.com:8258/doxManual/DoxService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IDoxService_SearchAgreements_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SearchAgreements"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IDoxService_SearchAgreements_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SearchAgreementsResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IDoxService">
<wsdl:operation name="SearchAgreements">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0/IDoxService/SearchAgreements" message="tns:IDoxService_SearchAgreements_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0/IDoxService/SearchAgreementsResponse" message="tns:IDoxService_SearchAgreements_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

xsd0

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0">
<xs:element name="SearchAgreements">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="searchRequest" nillable="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:any minOccurs="0" processContents="lax"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="SearchAgreementsResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SearchAgreementsResult" nillable="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:any minOccurs="0" processContents="lax"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

xsd1

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
<xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
<xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char">
<xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
<xs:simpleType name="duration">
<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
<xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
<xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Input to Service..unfortunetely,team has added few things so unable to retrieve output on SOAP UI.

```
   <AgreementSearchRequest xmlns="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <PageNo>1</PageNo>
    <PageSize>10</PageSize>
    <Source>IBFD</Source>
  </Header>
  <SearchCriteria>
    <AgreementId>10</AgreementId>
    <AgreementStatus>Search Status</AgreementStatus>
    <AgreementType>Search Type</AgreementType>
    <AgreementVersion>Search Version</AgreementVersion>
    <CompletedDate>2014-05-30T15:56:45.7533005+05:30</CompletedDate>
    <ContractingEntity>Search GCRS Code</ContractingEntity>
    <CounterpartyBranch>Search CP Branch</CounterpartyBranch>
    <CounterpartyEMID>Search CP EMID</CounterpartyEMID>
    <CounterpartyId>Search CP ID</CounterpartyId>
    <CounterpartyName>Search CP Name</CounterpartyName>
    <CounterpartyType>Search CP Type</CounterpartyType>
    <CreditContact>Search Contact</CreditContact>

    <IsOffshoreUser>true</IsOffshoreUser>
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <ProductCode>Search Code</ProductCode>:=
        <ProductName i:nil="true"/>
      </Product>
    </Products>
    <RXM>Search RXM</RXM>
    <RequestedDate>2014-05-30T15:56:45.758183+05:30</RequestedDate>
    <bankLegalEntity>Search LEgal Entity</bankLegalEntity>
    <bankLegalEntityCategory>Search Legal Entity Category</bankLegalEntityCategory>
    <UmbrellaCounterpartyEMID>Search Agent EMID</UmbrellaCounterpartyEMID>
    <UmbrellaCounterpartyName>Search Agent Name</UmbrellaCounterpartyName>
  </SearchCriteria>
```

I tried importing xsd and replacing xml file HTTPRIO Before execute as mentioned [here..](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_28281976.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfProduct">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Product" nillable="true" type="tns:Product" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfProduct" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfProduct" />
  <xs:complexType name="Product">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProductCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProductName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Product" nillable="true" type="tns:Product" />
    <xs:complexType name="AgreementSearchRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Header" nillable="true" type="tns:AgreementSearchRequestHeader" />
      <xs:element name="SearchCriteria" nillable="true" type="tns:AgreementSearchCriteria" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AgreementSearchRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:AgreementSearchRequest" />
  <xs:complexType name="AgreementSearchRequestHeader">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PageNo" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element name="PageSize" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element name="Source" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AgreementSearchRequestHeader" nillable="true" type="tns:AgreementSearchRequestHeader" />
  <xs:complexType name="AgreementSearchCriteria">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AgreementId" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AgreementStatus" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AgreementType" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AgreementVersion" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CompletedDate" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ContractingEntity" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CounterpartyBranch" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CounterpartyEMID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CounterpartyId" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CounterpartyName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CounterpartyType" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CreditContact" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Products" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfProduct" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RXM" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RequestedDate" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="egalEntity" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LegalEntityCategory" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UmbrellaCounterpartyEMID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UmbrellaCounterpartyName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AgreementSearchCriteria" nillable="true" type="tns:AgreementSearchCriteria" />
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: do you care sharing the wsdl?

Comment: sorry it is not from out side,it is on bank intranet..:( last week one of my friend tried accessing it

Comment: If you are on the Intranet and open a browser with the URL to the wsdl, e.g. http://*/DoxService.wsdl youu can retreive the contents of the wsdl file. That would be interesting to look at. Also if you have any example xml requests and responses?

Comment: ThanksLars,dontmind i had to remove some names and orginal machine names for security reasons..original  wsdl imports another wsdl inside and 2 more xsds which included in another wsdl.

Comment: Am really sorry,wsdl is from another team and they wanted to have generic one for few teams..so they made so complex :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on other views on vaiours forums(inc stack overflow) we have fixed the issue by fixing in 2 places.

Changed the remotable procedure generated by Delphi.Earlier it was a class of input parameter itself so we have changed to WideString

```
  SearchAgreements = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FsearchRequest: WideString ; 
    FsearchRequest_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SetsearchRequest(Index: Integer; const AsearchRequest: WideString ); 
    function  searchRequest_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published                
    property searchRequest: WideString   Index (IS_OPTN) read FsearchRequest write SetsearchRequest stored searchRequest_Specified;
  end;
```

And also we have modified HTTPRIO Before execute with minor modifications and we are able to send XML sucessfully to Service.

```
procedure HTTPRIO1SoapBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string;
  SOAPRequest: TStream);
var
 StrTemp,Fheader : TStringList;
  StrBeg,StrEnd,StrParam,StrParam1  : TStringList;
  StreamTemp : TStream;
  StrLst : TStringList;
  StrLstTmp: TStringList;

begin
  StrBeg:=TStringList.Create();
  StrEnd:=TStringList.Create();
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  StrTemp.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
  StrBeg.Text := StringReplace(StrTemp.Text,'&lt;','<',[RfReplaceAll]);
  StrEnd.Text := StringReplace(StrBeg.Text,'&gt;','>',[RfReplaceAll]);
  SOAPRequest.Position:=0;
  SOAPRequest.Size := 0; //Clear the Stream
  StrEnd.SaveToStream(SOAPRequest); //Reinitialise the stream with right string.
  SOAPRequest.Position :=0;
end;
```

We have done PHd on Webservices call with,so anyone facing similar issue can contact me.Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Web Service Toolkit](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit).

It has  a code generator that takes a wsdl and generate Pascal classes from it that interact with the web service.

Seems to be exactly what you need, but I do not know the specifics.

---

Then there are also my [Internet Tools](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/) for FreePascal (not Delphi).

They contain interpreter for XQuery  which is a general purpose XML processing language, so you can use it with every possible XML/HTML based API with far less code than using DOM methods. But it won't help you with anything WSDL specific, you need to write the XML for every request yourself.

Comment: Delphi also has webservice kit and it generates classes to deal with webservice.It is not working as expected.

Comment: I thought you were looking for another component for that, since it did not work... If you want to have it fixed, you probably need to give more details about the error than "no luck"