# Delphi SoapRequest converting < > to &lt; &gt;

Tags: xml, web-services, delphi, delphi-2010

[Continuation to this..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166011/is-it-possible-to-send-and-receive-xml-to-wsdl-function-using-delphi)

We are managed to generate logs on server side..when we pass input has widestring,we are getting XML with & lt; & gt;(not:-no space between characters) instead of < >..Is there any way restrict this in Delphi?

Even tried StringReplace in HTTPRIO1.BeforeExecute..

```
  LDocument := NewXMLDocument;
  LDocument.Active := True;
  LDocument.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  LDocument.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];
  ns := 'http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0';
  RootNode := LDocument.AddChild('AgreementSearchRequest');
  RootNode.Attributes['xmlns:i'] := 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
  RootNode.DeclareNamespace('', ns);

  HeaderNode := RootNode.AddChild('Header', ns);
  HeaderNode.AddChild('PageNo').Text := '1';
  HeaderNode.AddChild('PageSize').Text := '10';
  HeaderNode.AddChild('Source').Text := 'IFBD';

  SearchCriteriaNode := RootNode.AddChild('SearchCriteria', ns);
  SearchCriteriaNode.AddChild('AgreementId').Text := '5027222';
  SearchCriteriaNode.AddChild('IsOffshoreUser').Text := 'true';
  BankLegalNode := SearchCriteriaNode.AddChild('BankLegalEntities');
  LegalNode := BankLegalNode.AddChild('BankLegalEntity');
  LegalNode.AddChild('GCRS').Text := 'Search LEgal Entity';
  LegalNode.AddChild('BankLegalEntityName').Text :=
    'Search Legal Entity Category';
  DocSearchOut := SearchArgsResponse.Create();
  DoxSerchIn := SearchArgs.Create();
  DoxSerchIn.SearchArgs := LDocument.DocumentElement.XML;
  DoxService := GetIDoxService(True,'',HTTPRIO1);
  DocSearchOut :=DoxService.SearchAgreements(DoxSerchIn)
```

Tried converting before excute but when it convertes String to Stream its

```
procedure TFormDelegate.HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute(const MethodName: string;
  SOAPRequest: TStream);
var
  StrStrm : TStringStream;
  xml,xml1,xml2: TStringList;
begin
  ShowMessage(MethodName);
  Memo1.Clear;
    StrStrm := TStringStream.Create();
    xml := TStringList.Create;
    xml1 := TStringList.Create;
    xml2 := TStringList.Create;
    try
      xml.Text := StreamToString(SOAPRequest);
      xml2.Text := StringReplace(xml.Text,'&lt;','<', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
      xml1.Text := StringReplace(xml2.Text,'&gt;','>', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
      xml2.Text := StringReplace(xml1.Text,'<parameters>','', []);
      xml1.Text := StringReplace(xml2.Text,'</parameters>','', []);
      xml1.SaveToFile('response1.xml');
      //SOAPRequest := StringToStream(xml1.Text);
      SOAPRequest:=  StringToStream(xml1.Text);
    except
      xml.Free;
       xml1.Free;
        xml2.Free;
     StrStrm.Free;
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Append(StreamToString(SOAPRequest));
end;
```

Server side log..

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SearchAgreements xmlns="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0">
      <parameters>
   <searchRequest>&lt;AgreementSearchRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.bank.com/dox/service/v1.0.0"& gt;
  & lt;Header&gt;
    & lt;PageNo&gt;1& lt;/PageNo&gt;
    & lt;PageSize&gt;10& lt;/PageSize&gt;
    & lt;Source&gt;IFBD&l t;/Source&gt;
  & lt;/Header&gt;
  & lt;SearchCriteria& gt;
    & lt;AgreementId& gt;5027222& lt;/AgreementId& gt;
    & lt;IsOffshoreUser& gt;true&lt;/IsOffshoreUser& gt;
    & lt;bankLegalEntities&gt;
      & lt;bankLegalEntity& gt;
        & lt;GCRS&gt;Search LEgal Entity&lt;/GCRS&gt;
        & lt;bankLegalEntityName&gt;Search Legal Entity Category& lt;/bankLegalEntityName& gt;
      & lt;/bankLegalEntity& gt;
    & lt;/bankLegalEntities&gt;
  & lt;/SearchCriteria& gt;
& lt;/AgreementSearchRequest& gt;</searchRequest>
      </parameters>
    </SearchAgreements>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: if you want to send XML as an element value in a bigger XML document, you need to use the `<![CDATA[Your XML Data]]>`tag telling the parser to not parse the data block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have modified HTTPRIO Before execute with minor modifications and we are able to send XML sucessfully to Service.

```
procedure HTTPRIO1SoapBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string;
  SOAPRequest: TStream);
var
 StrTemp,Fheader : TStringList;
  StrBeg,StrEnd,StrParam,StrParam1  : TStringList;
  StreamTemp : TStream;
  StrLst : TStringList;
  StrLstTmp: TStringList;

begin
  StrBeg:=TStringList.Create();
  StrEnd:=TStringList.Create();
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  StrTemp.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
  StrBeg.Text := StringReplace(StrTemp.Text,'&lt;','<',[RfReplaceAll]);
  StrEnd.Text := StringReplace(StrBeg.Text,'&gt;','>',[RfReplaceAll]);
  SOAPRequest.Position:=0;
  SOAPRequest.Size := 0; //Clear the Stream
  StrEnd.SaveToStream(SOAPRequest); //Reinitialise the stream with right string.
  SOAPRequest.Position :=0;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is possible but I doubt it's what you want.

The following is not a technical description but my own view on this.
SOAP sends a request which is XML already and it will send your own data along.

If you would keep the less than `<` and greater than `>` characters the data you're sending would be treated as childnodes of the `data` node in the SOAPrequest.
You don't want that because it's data for whatever you want to achieve and not part of the SOAP.

What you could try is get the soaprequest, extract the xml from the `data` node as string.
Perform your stringreplace on that string and parse that as xml.

Hope this helped.

#### Edit

The problem lies in your SOAP message although its not really **a** problem.
If you read the above, you dont want your xml to be treated as childnodes but as a message when sending it with SOAP. So when you send it with SOAP the `<>` characters will be converted to `&lt; &gt;`.  If you want to convert that back to `<>` you will have to do that on the servers side. You might change it before sending but that makes no difference at all since it will be converted anyhow.
so doing this on the other end might be the only way.

Comment: Infact i tried String replace function,i believe when it is converting String to Stream(Input of Webservice) it is creating this issue

Comment: I would definetely loved to that on server side,unfortunetely webservice is owned by other team and it is really hard for me to convince them :(